# TypeError: Cannot read property 'body2' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, enzyme

When I test the component and I try to mount it, I get the error in the title.
When I dug into the stack trace I found the result in the file:

```
node_modules/@material-ui/core/Typography/Typography.js
```

and the code in this file is this:

```
var styles = function styles(theme) {
  return {
    root: {
      margin: 0
    },
    body2: theme.typography.body2, //this line makes the exception
........
```

adding the end of the stack trace:

```
at stytlesOrCreator (node_modules/@material-ui/core/Typography/Typography.js:34:29)
at Object.create (node_modules/@material-ui/styles/getStylesCreator/getStylesCreator.js:32:35)
at attach (node_modules/@material-ui/styles/makeStyles/makeStyles.js:113:32)
at func (node_modules/@material-ui/styles/makeStyles/makeStyles.js:258:7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgot to wrap the mounted component with material UI MuiThemeProvider

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was to import Typography from `"@mui/material` instead of `"@material-ui/core"`.

Comment: This question was posted prior to the release of ```@mui/material``` 